# How to pass data from one cell to another in the same tableView?

Tags: swift3

I have one cell with a `segmentedControl` and another cell with two date buttons (`Depart date` and `Return Date`).

- When I click segment 0 `Depart date` should be in enable mode and `Return date` should be in disable mode.
- When I click segment 1 both should be in enable mode.

Please provide sample code so I can understand easily.

Comment: You need to make action on segmentedControl change

Comment: @Masiama Yes i done but how to pass that data to date cell?

Comment: You have outlets of buttons and action of segmentedControl. When segmentedControl changed using switch you define which button to hide. I can write code example if you want

Comment: I improved the formatting and highlighting of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a var like this-

```
var index = 0
```

Add segment control target like this-

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Change value of `index` like this-

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
    {
        index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        yourtableView.reloadData()

    }
```

And finally in cellForRow enable or disable button with help of `index`.